# How to remove fluentd-elastisearch from Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, salt-stack

We have a Kubernetes 1.1 cluster on AWS provisioned using `kube-up.sh`.

Part of the base installation includes `fluentd-elastisearch`. We want to uninstall it. Specifically, we have been unsuccessful in removing the static pods running one-per-node.

We do not use the Kubernetes-hosted `fluentd-elastisearch`, but instead use an externally hosted instance. As far as I can tell, `fluentd-elastisearch` is not required to run Kubernetes, and so I have been *trying* to remove it from our cluster.

There seem to be two parts to the elastisearch setup.
The first is the `addon` defined on the master in `/etc/kubernetes/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch`. We moved this file out of the addons directory and manually deleted the associated Replication Controllers.

This leaves the static pods:

```
kube-ac --namespace=kube-system get pods
NAME                                                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fluentd-elasticsearch-ip-10-0-5-105.us-west-2.compute.internal   1/1       Running   1          6d
fluentd-elasticsearch-ip-10-0-5-124.us-west-2.compute.internal   1/1       Running   0          6d
fluentd-elasticsearch-ip-10-0-5-180.us-west-2.compute.internal   1/1       Running   0          6d
fluentd-elasticsearch-ip-10-0-5-231.us-west-2.compute.internal   1/1       Running   0          6d
```

We believe the static pods are launched on each node due to the presence on each node of `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/fluentd-es.yaml`.

This file appears to be placed by `salt` configuration `/srv/pillar/cluster-params.sls` which contains `enable_node_logging: 'true'`.

We flipped the flag to `'false'`, killed the existing nodes, allowing new ones be provisioned via the Auto Scaling Group. Unfortunately the newly spawned hosts still have the static `fluentd-elasticsearch` pods.

There are a couple of other possible files we think may be involved, on the master host:

```
/var/cache/kubernetes-install/kubernetes/saltbase/salt/fluentd-es/fluentd-es.yaml
/var/cache/salt/minion/files/base/fluentd-es/fluentd-es.yaml
```

We are hitting a wall with our lack of `salt` experience. Pointers most welcome.

Comment: Since you provisioned your cluster using kube-up you might be looking for this flag: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/aws/config-default.sh#L106

Comment: As far as I can tell, `ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING` only helps when creating a new cluster. I want to modify an existing cluster.

Comment: How did you configure fluentd to point to your external ES instance? We're currently looking to use external ES and deactivate the default fluentd-elasticsearch pods. Doesn't seem to be much info out there on this.

Answer (score 6):

I believe we have working steps to remove **fluentd** from a cluster which *already* has it installed.

1. Delete **fluentd-elastisearch** addon (on **master**)

   - `rm` (or `mv`) `/etc/kubernetes/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/`
   - Delete remnant ReplicationControllers:

     > kubectl  --namespace=kube-system delete rc elasticsearch-logging-v1 kibana-logging-v1
2. Disable logging in salt-stack (on **master**). This will prevent nodes spawned in the future from having the **fluentd static pod**.

   - In `/srv/pillar/cluster-params.sls` change existing settings to

     > enable_node_logging: 'false'
     >
     > logging_destination: 'none'
   - `salt '*' saltutil.clear_cache`
   - `salt '*' saltutil.sync_all`
3. On existing nodes, manually remove the **fluentd static pod**

   > rm /etc/kubernetes/manifests/fluentd-es.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the static pods by deleting the static pod manifest file. On all nodes run:

```
sudo rm /etc/kubernetes/manifests/fluentd-es.yaml
```

Here is the documentation on static pods:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/static-pods/

Comment: This is only a temporary solution. When new nodes spin up, they are configured using salt-stack and will have fluentd-es.yaml (and pod) present.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak configuration settings prior to spinning up your cluster that will skip installing some of the optional add ons. The settings are in [cluster/aws/config-default.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/config-default.sh) and to disable fluentd-es you should set `KUBE_LOGGING_DESTINATION=none` before running `kube-up.sh`.

Comment: In the comment he says that he needs to modify an already running cluster.

Comment: To echo @dward, this will only work for new clusters. Looking for a solution on an existing setup.